# Sort a dictionary by values that are instance attributes

Tags: python, linux, sorting, dictionary

I am currently working on a program written in Python 2.6.6. It uses a dictionary that looks like:

```
{ 'somekeystring': someobject("a name", 1, 3),
'anotherkey': someobject("another name", 2, 2),
'keythree': someobject("third name", 3, 1) }
```

The object has some attributes like:

```
name
startOrder
stopOrder
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the dictionary sorted. Once by someobject.startOrder, once by someobject.stopOrder.

I have tried

```
sortedByStartOrder = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].startOrder)
```

but this does not seem to work. The list items are sorted in the same order, no matter if I use startOrder or stopOrder in the example above.

Any hints?

Comment: Comparable code works fine for me... your attributes don't happen to be functions and not properties? Then `x[1].startOrder()` will work

Comment: "That does not seem to work" is a very vague problem description. What does it do, exactly? Does it throw an error? Does it go on strike for better cycles? Does it put the items in an unexpected order? If the last, give a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example seems to work for me:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

d = { 'how': P(3), 'hi': P(2), 'you': P(5), 'are': P(4) }
print list(d.iteritems())
print sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].x)
```

produces

```
>> [('how', <__main__.P instance at 0x7f92028e52d8>), ('you', <__main__.P instance at 0x7f92028e5368>), ('hi', <__main__.P instance at 0x7f92028e5320>), ('are', <__main__.P instance at 0x7f92028e53b0>)]
>> [('hi', <__main__.P instance at 0x7fc210e6c320>), ('how', <__main__.P instance at 0x7fc210e6c2d8>), ('are', <__main__.P instance at 0x7fc210e6c3b0>), ('you', <__main__.P instance at 0x7fc210e6c368>)]
```

I'd guess the problem isn't in the sort itself; there might be something wrong in the structures you're trying to sort.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for all your input! I wrote a simple example like Odexios' and it worked perfectly with

```
sortedByStartOrder = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].startOrder)
```

The clue was:

> I'd guess the problem isn't in the sort itself; there might be
>   something wrong in the structures you're trying to sort.

I went through my code and found a code passage where I set both variables to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [your own comparing function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) that is given to the `sorted` builtin in the keyword `cmp`.

```
def sort_by_start(obj1, obj2):
    # this is just an example using '>' and '<' as comparison operators
    # you can compare 1 and 2 using whatever methods you wish; just
    # return a negative number if 1 is less than 2, 0 if they are equal
    # or a positive number if 1 is greater than 2.
    if obj1.startOrder < obj2.startOrder:
        return -1
    if obj1.startOrder > obj2.startOrder:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

sorted(mydict.iteritems(), cmp=sort_by_start, key=lambda x: x[1])

def sort_by_stop(obj1, obj2):
    # let's make this more specific: imagine `stopOrder` is a string,
    # but we need to remove a prefix before we sort them alphabetically
    common_prefix = 'id-'  # or whatever
    comp1 = obj1.stopOrder.lstrip(common_prefix)
    comp2 = obj2.stopOrder.lstrip(common_prefix)
    if comp1 < comp2:
        return -1
    if comp1 > comp2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

sorted(mydict.iteritems(), cmp=sort_by_stop, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: As far as I can see, using a sorting function such as the one you proposed should be equivalent to what he wrote in the question

Comment: @Odexios yep, my example is very, very simple since there is not much information on what `startOrder` and `stopOrder` are ... I have added an explanatory comment on how to tweak such a function.